# The value of the function erf is always equal to zero

Tags: matlab, matrix, formula, calculation

I have been working on a project related to obtaining optical signals from the light of stars. My task is to model a histogram describing the distribution of Alpha coefficients. Alpha is a coefficient that determines the share of the useful signal per pixel. The number of pixels is 7 by 7, the pixel size is 1. The calculation function is this:

[image: The formula]

A strange error has appeared, in which the function `erf` is always equal to zero. Attached is the code I wrote. I also calculated a single array on my own, and what I got did not match the values ​​that I got in matlab

```
close all
dz = 0.5;
i_range = -3:1:3;
j_range = -3:1:3;

result_array = zeros(7,7);


for i_idx = 1:numel(i_range)
    i = i_range(i_idx);

    for j_idx = 1:numel(j_range)
        j = j_range(j_idx);

a = ((((i-1)/2)*erf(((i-1)*dz)/(sqrt(2))))-(i*erf((i*dz)/(sqrt(2))))+(((i+1)/2*erf(((i+1)*dz)/(sqrt(2))))+((1/(dz*(sqrt(2*pi))))*((exp(-(((i-1)^2)*(dz^2))/4))-(2*(exp((i^2)*(dz^2)/2)))+(exp(-(((i+1)^2)*(dz^2))/2)))))) * ((((j-1)/2)*erf(((j-1)*dz)/(sqrt(2))))-(j*erf((j*dz)/(sqrt(2))))+(((j+1)/2*erf(((j+1)*dz)/(sqrt(2))))+((1/(dz*(sqrt(2*pi))))*((exp(-(((j-1)^2)*(dz^2))/4))-(2*(exp((j^2)*(dz^2)/2)))+(exp(-(((j+1)^2)*(dz^2))/2))))));
        result_array(i_idx, j_idx) = a;
    end
end


inverted_result_array = max(result_array(:)) - result_array;


normalized_result_array = inverted_result_array - min(inverted_result_array(:));
normalized_result_array = normalized_result_array / max(normalized_result_array(:));

figure 
bar3(result_array);
xlabel('i');
ylabel('j');
zlabel('a');
title(['dz = ', num2str(dz)]);
```

Matrix I've calculated:
[image: data]

Comment: A formula like that, you cannot write on one line. Compute small parts of it separately. Most likely you have mismatching parentheses, or forgot a part, or who knows what else. It’s impossible to verify that line of code.

Comment: Please shrink your code to maybe only one element where you get a result different from MATLAB and post that, explaining why you think MATLAB is incorrect.

Comment: I can verify that simply your parenthesis are wrong, you made a typo. `[...](dz^2))/2))))))*[...]` Some of those close too late, should have closed earlier.